# a null exception when saving an image

Tags: c#

I have a button to save an image to my database using these steps:

1. I click a button to choose the image using `OpenFileDialog` and preview it using a `PictureBox`.
2. I click a button to save it to the database.

If the user chooses no image, I want to save an image from an `ImageList`, so I used this code to do this:

```
if (emppic.Image == null)
{
    emppic.Image = imageList1.Images[0];
}
byte[] byteImage;
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
emppic.Image.Save(ms, emppic.Image.RowFormat);
byteImage = ms.ToArray();
```

Then I save it normally to my database using a stored procedure.

When I try to add using this code without choosing an Image I get this error:

> ArgumentNullException was unhandled

What could be the issue?

Comment: Do you have any images in the list?

Comment: You can put more of your code please?

Comment: sorry but i don't know which part may be able to help because the rest of the code work without problems

Comment: any spasific part u need me to add ?

Comment: Put the code where the user chooses, or not, an image

Comment: look the button add an image anyway which displayed on the pictureBox so if the user added any image the adding process complete normally if not i get an error but it should to display the imageBox Image then save it .

Comment: so the code below work anyway at the 2 cases

Comment: Be sure to use the Image property in the PictureBox and not BackgroundImage.
Make sure you have elements and that these elements are correct.